How do I correctly clone and set up VulkanMemoryAllocator for a C++ Vulkan project
I am in the process of learning to implement and use the Vulkan API for graphics programming.  I am using a Dell computer with an Arch Linux OS and a g++ version 14.1.1 C++ compiler.  I am going through the tutorial on the vulkan website at https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Vertex_buffers/Staging_buffer.  AS I go through the tutorial I am breaking up the highly coupled implementation within the tutorial into separate files and classes to make each section a bit easier to handle as an individual chunk of code.  Simplified to display data relevant to this question, my current directory layout for the  VulkanApplication code base I am writing is shown below.  Currently the code compiles in a debug mode and the executable is piped to VulkanApplication->VulkanApplication->build->debug after running cmake.
VulkanApplication
└── VulkanApplication
    ├── build
    │   └── debug
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── graphics_pipeline.cpp
    |-- all other .cpp files   
    ├── include
    │   ├── graphics_pipeline.hpp
    |   |-- All other .hpp files
    ├── shaders
        ├── shader.frag
        ├── shader.frag.spv
        ├── shader.vert
        └── shader.vert.spv

Currently the graphics_pipeline.cpp file implements the Vulkan vkAllocateMemory function to assign memory to index and vertex buffers.  However, this built in function is limited by the physical device and is also called for each memory allocation instead of once to assign a larger block of memory which can be chunked out.  The tutorial recommends either writing your own custom allocator or using the `VulkanMemoryAllocator`` library stored at the following address, which is robust and well tested, but the tutorial does not cover how to implement it
https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator
Following the instructions in the github page I manually cloned the package into my lower-level VulkanApplication directory which stores all of my .cpp files, which is reflected below.
VulkanApplication
    └── VulkanApplication
        ├── build
        │   └── debug
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── graphics_pipeline.cpp
        |-- all other .cpp files   
        |-- VulkanMemoryAllocator
        |   |_ All files for VMA library
        ├── include
        │   ├── graphics_pipeline.hpp
        |   |-- All other .hpp files
        ├── shaders
            ├── shader.frag
            ├── shader.frag.spv
            ├── shader.vert
            └── shader.vert.spv

Next I modified the include statements in the graphics_pipeline.hpp file to implement the VulkanMemoryAllocator package with this following line.
#include "../VulkanMemoryAllocator/include/vk_mem_alloc.h"

Then I updated the implementation in the GraphicsPipeline class within the graphics_pipeline.cpp file to replace the vkAllocateMemory function with these lines in the constructor.
VmaAllocatorCreateInfo allocatorInfo = {};
allocatorInfo.physicalDevice = physicalDevice;
allocatorInfo.device = device;
allocatorInfo.instance = this->instance; // Set your VkInstance here

if (vmaCreateAllocator(&allocatorInfo, &allocator) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create VMA allocator!");
}

In addition the destructor contains lines to clean up the allocations, and I create this function which is called in several places to allocate the chunks.
void GraphicsPipeline::createBufferWithVMA(VkDeviceSize size, VkBufferUsageFlags usage, 
                                           VmaMemoryUsage memoryUsage, VkBuffer& buffer, 
                                           VmaAllocation& allocation) {
    VkBufferCreateInfo bufferInfo = {};
    bufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    bufferInfo.size = size;
    bufferInfo.usage = usage;
    bufferInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

    VmaAllocationCreateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.usage = memoryUsage;

    if (vmaCreateBuffer(allocator, &bufferInfo, &allocInfo, &buffer, &allocation, nullptr) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create buffer with VMA!");
    }
}

I am confident in my implementation within the code, but I seem to have a linking problem which I think is caused by how I set up the VulkanMemoryAllocator code.  To set it up, I followed the instructions in the github page and I cd'd into the VulkanMemoryAllocator package and typed these instructions.
cmake -S . -B build
# Since VMA has no source files, you can skip to installation immediately
cmake --install build --prefix build/install

which leads to the following output. (NOTE: This is an example after being built once)
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to:/home/my_username/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/VulkanMemoryAllocator/build

-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date:/home/my_username/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/VulkanMemoryAllocator/build/install/include
-- Up-to-date:/home/my_username/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/VulkanMemoryAllocator/build/install/include/vk_mem_alloc.h
-- Up-to-date:/home/my_username/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/VulkanMemoryAllocator/build/install/share/cmake/VulkanMemoryAllocator/VulkanMemoryAllocatorConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date:/home/my_username/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/VulkanMemoryAllocator/build/install/share/cmake/VulkanMemoryAllocator/VulkanMemoryAllocatorConfigVersion.cmake

I then update my CMakeLists.txt file within the lower VulkanAllocation directory to contain these two lines.
find_package(VulkanMemoryAllocator CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(YourGameEngine PRIVATE GPUOpen::VulkanMemoryAllocator)

my exact CMakeLists.txt file is shown below.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29.6)
project(VulkanApplication)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Include ExternalProject module to manage external dependencies
include(ExternalProject)

# Define GLFW as an external project
ExternalProject_Add(
    glfw
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
    GIT_TAG latest
    CMAKE_ARGS -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF
               -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF
               -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF
               -DGLFW_BUILD_INSTALL=OFF
               -DGLFW_BUILD_WAYLAND=OFF
               -DGLFW_BUILD_X11=ON
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glfw
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

# Find the Vulkan package
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

# Find the glslangValidator tool
find_program(GLSLANG_VALIDATOR glslangValidator HINTS "$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/bin" REQUIRED)

# Check glslangValidator version
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${GLSLANG_VALIDATOR} --version
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GLSLANG_VALIDATOR_VERSION
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

message(STATUS "Found glslangValidator: ${GLSLANG_VALIDATOR}")
message(STATUS "glslangValidator version: ${GLSLANG_VALIDATOR_VERSION}")

# Shader files
set(SHADERS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders/shader.vert
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders/shader.frag
)

# Compile shaders to SPIR-V
foreach(SHADER ${SHADERS})
    get_filename_component(FILE_NAME ${SHADER} NAME)
    set(SPIRV ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders/${FILE_NAME}.spv)

    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${SPIRV}
        COMMAND ${GLSLANG_VALIDATOR} -V ${SHADER} -o ${SPIRV}
        DEPENDS ${SHADER}
        COMMENT "Compiling ${SHADER} to SPIR-V"
    )

    list(APPEND SPIRV_SHADERS ${SPIRV})
endforeach()

# Add custom target to build all shaders
add_custom_target(ShadersTarget ALL DEPENDS ${SPIRV_SHADERS})

# Define the executable
add_executable(VulkanApplication 
               main.cpp
               window.cpp
               application.cpp
               validation_layers.cpp
               queues.cpp
               devices.cpp
               graphics_pipeline.cpp
)

# Make VulkanApplication dependent on ShadersTarget
add_dependencies(VulkanApplication ShadersTarget)

# Include GLFW and Vulkan directories
ExternalProject_Get_Property(glfw source_dir binary_dir)
target_include_directories(VulkanApplication PRIVATE ${source_dir}/include)
target_include_directories(VulkanApplication PRIVATE ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Include VMA header file directory
target_include_directories(VulkanApplication PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

find_package(VulkanMemoryAllocator CONFIG REQUIRED)
# Link the GLFW and Vulkan libraries and add the necessary linker flags
add_dependencies(VulkanApplication glfw)
target_link_libraries(VulkanApplication PRIVATE ${binary_dir}/src/libglfw3.a Vulkan::Vulkan GPUOpen::VulkanMemoryAllocator dl pthread X11 Xxf86vm Xrandr Xi)

# Set the output directory for the executable
set_target_properties(VulkanApplication PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)

# Additional flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native -mtune=native -fPIE")

# Set debug-specific compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -Wpedantic -g")
# Set release-specific compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -O2")

However, when I run cmake, I get the following error associated with VulkanMemoryAllocator, indicating that it is looking for a config file.
-- Found glslangValidator: /bin/glslangValidator
-- glslangValidator version: Glslang Version: 11:14.2.0
ESSL Version: OpenGL ES GLSL 3.20 glslang Khronos. 14.2.0
GLSL Version: 4.60 glslang Khronos. 14.2.0
SPIR-V Version 0x00010600, Revision 1
GLSL.std.450 Version 100, Revision 1
Khronos Tool ID 8
SPIR-V Generator Version 11
GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl version 100
ARB_GL_gl_spirv version 100
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:87 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "VulkanMemoryAllocator" with any of the following names:

    VulkanMemoryAllocatorConfig.cmake
    vulkanmemoryallocator-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "VulkanMemoryAllocator" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "VulkanMemoryAllocator_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
  above files.  If "VulkanMemoryAllocator" provides a separate development
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-- Found glslangValidator: /bin/glslangValidator
-- glslangValidator version: Glslang Version: 11:14.2.0
ESSL Version: OpenGL ES GLSL 3.20 glslang Khronos. 14.2.0
GLSL Version: 4.60 glslang Khronos. 14.2.0
SPIR-V Version 0x00010600, Revision 1
GLSL.std.450 Version 100, Revision 1
Khronos Tool ID 8
SPIR-V Generator Version 11
GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl version 100
ARB_GL_gl_spirv version 100
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:87 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "VulkanMemoryAllocator" with any of the following names:

    VulkanMemoryAllocatorConfig.cmake
    vulkanmemoryallocator-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "VulkanMemoryAllocator" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "VulkanMemoryAllocator_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
  above files.  If "VulkanMemoryAllocator" provides a separate development
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [Makefile:369: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

What am I doing wrong.  I feel like I am following the instructions in the github page to a tee, but I can not get this code to compile with the VulkanMemoryAllocator package.
The github instructions for VulkanMemoryAllocator also states that the find_package(VulkanMemoryAllocator CONFIG REQUIRED) can be replaced with add_subdirectory(VulkanMemoryAllocator); however, if I to this, the compilation process fails with the following linker error.  This indicates that it detects the .h file, but it does not detect a static or dynamic library that defines the functions or their .cpp files.
[100%] Linking CXX executable VulkanApplication
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/graphics_pipeline.cpp.o: in function `GraphicsPipeline::GraphicsPipeline(VkDevice_T*, VkExtent2D, VkFormat, VkPhysicalDevice_T*, VkQueue_T*, std::vector<Vertex, std::allocator<Vertex> > const&, std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > const&, VkInstance_T*&)':
/home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:50:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to `vmaCreateAllocator'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/graphics_pipeline.cpp.o: in function `GraphicsPipeline::~GraphicsPipeline()':
/home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:83:(.text+0x524): undefined reference to `vmaDestroyAllocator'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/graphics_pipeline.cpp.o: in function `GraphicsPipeline::createVertexBuffer()':
/home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:454:(.text+0x213a): undefined reference to `vmaMapMemory'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:456:(.text+0x217c): undefined reference to `vmaUnmapMemory'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:463:(.text+0x21ef): undefined reference to `vmaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/graphics_pipeline.cpp.o: in function `GraphicsPipeline::createIndexBuffer()':
/home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:496:(.text+0x2280): undefined reference to `vmaMapMemory'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:498:(.text+0x22c2): undefined reference to `vmaUnmapMemory'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:505:(.text+0x2335): undefined reference to `vmaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/graphics_pipeline.cpp.o: in function `GraphicsPipeline::cleanupVertexBuffer()':
/home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:529:(.text+0x2384): undefined reference to `vmaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/graphics_pipeline.cpp.o: in function `GraphicsPipeline::cleanupIndexBuffer()':
/home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:536:(.text+0x23c0): undefined reference to `vmaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/graphics_pipeline.cpp.o: in function `GraphicsPipeline::createBufferWithVMA(unsigned long, unsigned int, VmaMemoryUsage, VkBuffer_T*&, VmaAllocation_T*&)':
/home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/C++/VulkanApplication/VulkanApplication/graphics_pipeline.cpp:634:(.text+0x2c5e): undefined reference to `vmaCreateBuffer'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/build.make:195: VulkanApplication] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:157: CMakeFiles/VulkanApplication.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2


#include "../VulkanMemoryAllocator/include/vk_mem_alloc.h" You got that one wrong as well - when linking the library GPUOpen::VulkanMemoryAllocator as a CMake target,  ../VulkanMemoryAllocator/include had already been added to your projects include paths. So it's just #include <vk_mem_alloc.h>.

This is more of a CMake issue. You need to point the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to your VMA directory in order for find_package to pick up the config properly. To prevent such problems, I recommend you use a package manager (e.g., vcpkg) to handle dependencies and setup all the paths for you.

@Carsten I took your advice and am now using vcpkg and it is still giving the same linking errors.

The VMA library is header only, but the missing definitions are gated behind a preprocessor macro. Did you take note of that? In particular, see point two of the quickstart documentation

@Jon Does it still give you the "Could not find a package configuration file ..." during configuration? Did you remember to put in VMA_IMPLEMENTATION into one of your cpp files before including the VMA headers?

I think you glossed over a crucial bit in the README:

After calling either find_package or add_subdirectory simply link the library. This automatically handles configuring the include directory.

Indeed, you can replace your
find_package(VulkanMemoryAllocator CONFIG REQUIRED)

line with
add_subdirectory(VulkanMemoryAllocator)

and it should provide the correct target for you to link against.

@Botjie I forgot to mention that I already tried this.  If I replace the find_package with add_subdirectory command it fails with linking errors.  I will update my question to highlight these.
